# Restkit sendObject not posting object when params is set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, restkit

I'm trying to POST an object using Restkit, but when I set some extra parameters, it doesn't post the object anymore.

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"mic" forKey:@"type"];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] sendObject:rating toResourcePath:@"/mic" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.delegate = self;
        loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
        loader.params = params; // without this line, the 'rating' object is posted, 
    }];
```

I need to send extra POST parameters which isn't included within the object, with the code above, I receive the extra "type" parameter via POST, but the object isn't received.

I read the Parameters section of the documentation https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping - the documentation must be a bit old as the method has changed, but the concept is the same. I don't see what i'm doing wrong...help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it's a bit long winded because when using `sendObject` and `loadObject` unfortunately the method assumes you will get back the same object in return as the one you're sending. This isn't the case for me as it will either return the same object...or an error object. So this is how I done it

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/mic" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
        loader.delegate = self;
        loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
        NSError* error;
        RKObjectMapping* serializationMapping = [manager.mappingProvider serializationMappingForClass:[Rating class]];
        RKObjectSerializer* serializer = [RKObjectSerializer serializerWithObject:rating mapping:serializationMapping];
        id params = [serializer serializationForMIMEType:manager.serializationMIMEType error:&error];

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error serializing object");
        }

        NSLog(@"Params class: %@", [params class]);

        if ([params respondsToSelector:@selector(setValue:forKey:)])
            [params performSelector:@selector(setValue:forKey:) withObject:@"mic" withObject:@"type"];

        loader.params = params;
    }];
```

I serialised the object within the block, then added a parameter to the the resulting dictionary. That way, I don't have to give the object an extra "type" property...it would mean I would have to add that to every object I plan on posting.

Answer (score 3):

Search RestKit's source for "prepareURLRequest"

First line reads:

```
    if ((self.sourceObject && self.params == nil) && (self.method == RKRequestMethodPOST || self.method == RKRequestMethodPUT))
```

So, your sourceObject is valid, but your params are not nil, so your object never gets serialized.

Also, when your object gets serialized successfully, it gets put into the "params" value. So, if you say "loader.params = params" you're overwriting your initial object.

Best solution here would be to change "sourceObject" so that it has the extra params in it, and create the mappings for it accordingly.

Other than that, you may have to use a more generic method (look at loadObject) and in your block, change the method to "POST" and change build your post-data block by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found a solution though, please check my answer. Please +1 if you think it's a good solution.

Comment: After looking at your solution, it will work. What might be a better solution would be passing the "type" parameter in the URL itself.    So, it might look like http://something.com/REST/mic/objectArray  In this case, you're only posting your object, but extra params about the action get passed in the URL.

Comment: The only problem with that is that my REST application checks `$_POST` for the parameter `type` otherwise it doesn't know it's a POST form method. This is my first REST application so I may be doing things awkwardly, but the reason I do that is because I can't just say `if ($_GET)` because there is always $_GET data as it's a Joomla based site. Have you made REST applications before? How do you distinguish between GET, POST, PUT and DELETE?